# What causes "Network Change Was Detected" warning on a machine with static IP?

Tags: networking, security

My machine's internal (my home network) IP address is static. Very frequently I see an error in chrome or Vivaldi indicating that the `Network Change Was Detected`.

I tried to search on-line and what I've found doesn't really seem to apply (restart chrome, etc...).

How do I go about troubleshooting this? What causes this problem? Is this a network security problem? Is my network somehow getting changed (I don't even know what that would mean)?

**Update**

My public address address has not changed since I started tracking it, but I keep seeing this issue.

I wonder if this is somehow related to https?

Comment: Maybe ask the browser vendors exactly what that message means? Could be a public IP address change, could be a routing change, maybe even a DNS change ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue continued occurring, until I happen to find that [Disabling IPv6](https://askubuntu.com/a/906688/176590) had worked on ubuntu.

I have disabled my IPv6 (it was set to automatic) & I have not seen this problem occur since the change (for the past week).

I will post an update here if I see the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if I'm right or not but I suppose its caused because your computer's Public IP was changed perhaps you reconnected to the network. And I wouldn't say its a network security problem since Public IPs are dynamic they change if you reconnect to the network.

Comment: I see, I'll try to track changes to my public ip address to see if that's cause of the issue, will report back